# Vue.Draggable: How to "drag an item onto another item" instead of adding/removing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable, sortablejs

Using https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

I have a question on how to achieve the classic example of dragging a file into a folder.
I see the `@change` event gets data about the dragged item, but not about the item that its being dragged onto.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Here's an example of what it would look like more or less, but obviously I would like to be able to reassign the `file.folder_name` inside that `onFoldersChange` - somehow.
https://jsfiddle.net/u5nb48cs/2/

Thanks!

Comment: I *think*, if you want to make the Folders contain draggable items, that each Folder would need to be a `draggable`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the folders to contain files, each folder needs to be able to hold files and be a draggable destination.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    folders: [{
      name: "Folder1",
      contents: []
    }, {
      name: "Folder2",
      contents: []
    }, {
      name: "Folder3",
      contents: []
    }],
    files: [{
      name: "foo",
      folder_name: "Folder1"
    }, {
      name: "bar",
      folder_name: 'Folder2'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    onFoldersChange() {
      console.log(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.dragArea {
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sortable/1.4.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Draggable/master/dist/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Vue Draggable</h1>
  <div class="drag">
    <h2>Folders</h2>
    <div v-for="(element, index) in folders" :key="index">{{element.name}}
      <draggable v-model="element.contents" class="dragArea" :options="{group:{ put:'files'}}" @change="onFoldersChange">
        <div v-for="item in element.contents">
          {{item.name}}
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>

    <h2>Files</h2>
    <draggable v-model="files" class="dragArea" :options="{group:{ name:'files'}}">
      <div v-for="(element, index) in files" :key="index">{{element.name}}</div>
    </draggable>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, this definitely gets it a bit closer. However another requirement is that the Folders need to be draggable too. 

The key is that I need a way to know "which file got dropped into which folder" via some sort of sortableJS event.  From there, I can write logic that modifies data in the server. 

Any ideas? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can put another `<draggable v-mode="folders">` around the section that displays the folders. That allows the folders to be rearranged.