# How can I drag items "into" other items, like a file and folder with VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

My project consists of VueJs 3 and vuedraggable.next.

So im trying to build a interface for managing questions that are organized into subjects an different topics. And moving and rearranging them separately seems to work. But im trying to figure out how I can move a question "into" another topic with drag and drop.

[I found this 4 year old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061794/vue-draggable-how-to-drag-an-item-onto-another-item-instead-of-adding-removin) but without an accepted answer that I can work with. I have made [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hssmu8?file=src/App.vue) example to make it more understandable what im asking for.

I was thinking of adding my own, second layer, of draggable elements with the plain [HTML drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) and somehow make the topics a "drop zone". With that approach I might grab the `topic_id` and `subject_id`, store that data, and remove the element from `questions` vue data list.

Comment: The nested example from their website might be helpful for reference: https://sortablejs.github.io/vue.draggable.next/#/nested-example

Comment: Thanks! Fiddled with nested, but no luck :/ couldent drag the questions into topics